# Is it possible to create a shortcut/symbolic link to a folder in unity launcher?

Tags: unity, symbolic-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Unity, how do I make desktop shortcuts (a la Windows, OSX)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55408/in-unity-how-do-i-make-desktop-shortcuts-a-la-windows-osx)
>   [How can you access a folder you want quickly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126446/how-can-you-access-a-folder-you-want-quickly)

I want to create a shortcut for a folder on unity. How is it possible?

---

Edit:- I would think of this shortcut as quick-link in windows for referencing a frequently used item easily without having to navigate the directory structure every time I need to access it.

Comment: Do you mean Unity launcher?

Comment: @anwar, yes i want to create shortcut to a folder deep inside the hierarchy on unity launcher. Like quick links in windows xp.

Comment: @Ankit see the answer whether if fits your need

Comment: You may be happy with bookmarks. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/126446/how-can-you-access-a-folder-you-want-quickly

Comment: @Takkat +1,  Simple and easy way to add a link to unity. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For adding application launchers, see this more generic question:

- [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

I think, you are asking to add a launcher pointing to a location which will be opened  with nautilus upon click.

To do so, Follow this:

1. First create a file naming `custom` in your desktop.
2. Open the file with a text editor (such as gedit or leafpad etc) by double clicking it
3. Copy the below lines and paste them in the file

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Custom location
   Comment=Location
   Exec=nautilus /mnt
   Icon=nautilus
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=false
   ```

   Change `/mnt` in the line `Exec=nautilus /mnt` with a desired location. 
   You can also change the string in `Name=Custom location` line.

   Save it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
4. Then again rename the file, pressing selecting it and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>. Add a `.desktop` at the end of the file.
5. Copy the file to your desired location. Note, if you delete the file later, the launcher will not work. I assume you copied it in `~/.local/share/applications` folder.
6. Then select the file and drag and drop it in the Unity launcher.

That's it. A new launcher will be created which will open the desired location when clicked.

Comment: great, that's what I wanted. Thanks a lot :).It's working. Could you please redirect me to a location from I can read some documentation regarding "Comment", "Icon", "Terminal" and "StartupNotify".

Comment: @Ankit [There you go](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)